# how can I override robots in a sub folder

Tags: robots.txt

I have a sub-domain for testing purposes.  I have set robots.txt to disallow this folder.

Some of the results are still showing for some reason.  I thought it may be because I hadn't set up the robots.txt originally and Google hadn't removed some of them yet.

Now I'm worried that the robots.txt files within the individual joomla sites in this folder are causing Google to keep indexing them.  Ideally I would like to stop that from happening because I don't want to have to remember to turn robots.txt back to follow when they go live (just in case).

Is there a way to override these explicitly with a robots.txt in a folder above this folder?

Comment: Please read the documentation of how google interprets the robots.txt file. It is all explained in there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as a crawler is concerned, robots.txt exists *only* in the site's root directory. There is no concept of a hierarchy of robots.txt files.

So if you have http://example.com and http://foo.example.com, then you would need two different robots.txt files: one for example.com and one for foo.example.com. When Googlebot reads the robots.txt file for foo.example.com, it does not take into account the robots.txt for example.com.

When Google bot is crawling example.com, it will not under any circumstances interpret the robots.txt file for foo.example.com. And when it's crawling foo.example.com, it will not interpret the robots.txt for example.com.

Does that answer your question?

### More info

When Googlebot crawls foo.com, it will read foo.com/robots.txt and use the rules in that file. It *will not* read and follow the rules in foo.com/portfolio/robots.txt or foo.com/portfolio/mydummysite.com/robots.txt. See the first two sentences of my original answer.

I don't fully understand what you're trying to prevent, probably because I don't fully understand your site hierarchy. But you can't change a crawler's behavior on mydummysite.com by changing the robots.txt file at foo.com/robots.txt or foo.com/portfolio/robots.txt.

Comment: Not really, sorry, I already thought that.  What I'm asking about is foo.com is one domain, then foo.com/portfolio/mydummysite.com is another folder within that domain, so it would take account of the Robots.txt in the root, then in the portfolio folder there is another, and finally in mydummysite.com there is a third, but say the mydummysite.com has already been indexed prior to me adding the robots.txt to the portfolio folder, can I override it somehow by using the portfolio folder in hindsight.  My guess is no, but I wanted someone more knowledgeable to tell me I'm right/wrong.